# frustrated again

Tags: system-installation, wubi

I decided to try linux again...

ok---windows.....create a DVD for the download and use the suggested program to burn such. Click link. That program virtually destroys ones computer with the added junk junk. Even hijacks browsers. Takes hours to get rid of the stuff if at all. Safe Mode helps some. Mature ? maybe

ok..burned an iso image. Says your computer will boot from such. NO LUCK. I tried the HELP ME BOOT option and that even does not work. ERROR MESSAGE :::::::::::

```
08-26 22:14 INFO   root: === wubi 14.04 rev286 ===
08-26 22:14 DEBUG  root: Logfile is c:\users\david\appdata\local\temp\wubi-14.04-rev286.log
08-26 22:14 DEBUG  root: sys.argv = ['main.pyo', '--exefile="D:\\wubi.exe"']
08-26 22:14 DEBUG  CommonBackend: data_dir=C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pylD855.tmp\data
08-26 22:14 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: 7z=C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pylD855.tmp\bin\7z.exe
08-26 22:14 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: startup_folder=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
08-26 22:14 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Fetching basic info...
08-26 22:14 DEBUG  CommonBackend: original_exe=D:\wubi.exe
08-26 22:14 DEBUG  CommonBackend: platform=win32
08-26 22:14 DEBUG  CommonBackend: osname=nt
08-26 22:14 DEBUG  CommonBackend: language=en_US
08-26 22:14 DEBUG  CommonBackend: encoding=cp1252
08-26 22:14 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: arch=amd64
08-26 22:14 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Parsing isolist=C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pylD855.tmp\data\isolist.ini
08-26 22:14 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-i386
08-26 22:14 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-amd64
08-26 22:14 DEBUG  CommonBackend: 


None
08-26 22:39 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Finished get_metalink
08-26 22:39 DEBUG  TaskList: New task get_file_md5
08-26 22:39 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Running get_file_md5...
08-26 22:39 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Finished get_file_md5
08-26 22:39 ERROR  CommonBackend: Invalid md5 for ISO C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso (c4d4d037d7d0a05e8f526d18aa25fb5e != a4fc15313ef2a516bfbf83ce44281535)
None
08-26 22:39 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished check_iso
08-26 22:39 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished use_cd
08-26 22:39 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running extract_kernel...
08-26 22:39 ERROR  TaskList: Could not retrieve the required installation files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 618, in extract_kernel
Exception: Could not retrieve the required installation files
08-26 22:39 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
08-26 22:39 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
08-26 22:39 ERROR  root: Could not retrieve the required installation files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 130, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 205, in run_cd_menu
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 122, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 228, in run_cd_boot
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 618, in extract_kernel
Exception: Could not retrieve the required installation files
08-26 22:41 INFO   root: === wubi 14.04 rev286 ===
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  root: Logfile is c:\users\david\appdata\local\temp\wubi-14.04-rev286.log
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  root: sys.argv = ['main.pyo', '--exefile="C:\\ubuntu\\uninstall-wubi.exe"']
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend: data_dir=C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp\data
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: 7z=C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp\bin\7z.exe
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: startup_folder=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Fetching basic info...
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend: original_exe=C:\ubuntu\uninstall-wubi.exe
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend: platform=win32
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend: osname=nt
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend: language=en_US
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend: encoding=cp1252
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: arch=amd64
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Parsing isolist=C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp\data\isolist.ini
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-i386
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-amd64
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-i386
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-amd64
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-amd64
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-amd64
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-i386
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-i386
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-amd64
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-i386
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-i386
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-amd64
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Fetching host info...
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: registry_key=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows version=vista
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_version2=Windows Vista (TM) Home Premium
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_sp=Service Pack 1
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_build=6001
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: gmt=-5
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: country=US
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: timezone=America/New_York
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_username=DAVID
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_full_name=DAVID
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_directory=C:\Users\DAVID
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language_code=1033
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language=English
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: processor_name=Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  T3200  @ 2.00GHz
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: bootloader=vista
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: system_drive=Drive(C: hd 111863.894531 mb free ntfs)
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(C: hd 111863.890625 mb free ntfs)
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(D: cd 0.0 mb free cdfs)
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: uninstaller_path=C:\ubuntu\uninstall-wubi.exe
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_target_dir=C:\ubuntu
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_distro_name=Ubuntu
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_id=67699721
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_layout=us
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_variant=
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend: python locale=('en_US', 'cp1252')
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend: locale=en_US.UTF-8
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: total_memory_mb=1915.26171875
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching ISOs on USB devices
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local CDs
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\vmlinuz.efi
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:   parsing info from str=Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS "Trusty Tahr" - Release i386 (20140722.2)
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  Distro:   parsed info={'name': 'Ubuntu', 'subversion': 'Release', 'version': '14.04.1', 'build': '20140722.2', 'codename': 'Trusty Tahr', 'arch': 'i386'}
08-26 22:41 INFO   Distro: Found a valid CD for Ubuntu: D:\
08-26 22:41 INFO   root: Running the uninstaller...
08-26 22:41 INFO   CommonBackend: This is the uninstaller running
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: __init__...
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: on_init...
08-26 22:41 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\DAVID\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl83DE.tmp\translations, languages=['en_US', 'en']
08-26 22:41 INFO   WindowsFrontend: Operation cancelled
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: frontend.quit
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: frontend.on_quit
08-26 22:41 DEBUG  root: application.on_quit
08-26 22:41 INFO   root: sys.exit
```

Sorry Folks but it says to check this log file and I c/c/p

struck out again..post too long...above is the end...

Comment: For future reference, use http://paste.ubuntu.com for long logs.

Comment: @muru At least it's in a code tag.

Comment: @Mew I put the logs into them. :) Also he said that the logs are too long and this is only part of them.